# Excel - Returning column header of maximum value (return random column if duplicate max values)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to put together a formula where Excel looks in a row and returns a column header of the maximum value BUT if there are duplicate maximum values, randomly return one of the matching column headers. I've got the `INDEX` `MATCH` `MAX` thing working which returns the first instance of a maximum value Left to right, but need to figure out the returning a random duplicate, if it exists.

I got as far as finding something that will return the 2nd highest - but again it's biased buy looking Left to right.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(..., MAX))` approach is the right way to go but the formula could be simplified by using an arrayed SMALL or AGGREGATE with the COUNTIF supplying the *k* number to point to the result column header.

```
 =INDEX(A$1:M$1,AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(A1:M1)/(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3)), RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(A3:M3,MAX(A3:M3)))))
```

[image]

As mentioned, RANDBETWEEN is a volatile function and will recalculate whenever anything in any open workbook changes.

Comment: Nice, totally [forgot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57080674/9758194) about that method. + and if OP sees this he should accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you got [access](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) to the `TEXTJOIN` function it would be a few steps:

- First we need to know which brands fullfill the criteria of having the `MAX` of that row and concatenate those names:

  ```
  =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3),A1:M1,""))
  ```

> **Note** This is an array formula and need to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

- The second step is to get a random number between 1 and the number of brands that have the `MAX` number:

  ```
  =RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(A3:M3,MAX(A3:M3)))
  ```
- Now we got everything we need to implement in a formula described [here](https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-nth-word-from-text-string) where we can extract the `nth` word from a string. Instead of spaces (your brands might include spaces) we will use the comma as a word seperator. So if we throw all the formulas together:

  ```
  =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3),A1:M1,"")),",",REPT(" ",LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3),A1:M1,""))))),(RANDBETWEEN(1,COUNTIF(A3:M3,MAX(A3:M3)))-1)*LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3),A1:M1,"")))+1,LEN(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(A3:M3=MAX(A3:M3),A1:M1,"")))))
  ```

Now this will give you a random Brand name that fullfills the criteria of having the `MAX` value on that row.

---

Follow the provided link to see if your Excel subscription gives you access to `TEXTJOIN`. Also note, since there is a volatile function in the formula (`RANDBETWEEN`), the formula will constantly recalculate.